# wpf: name in one column, TextBox/ListBox/Slider in the other

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview

I would like to display a bunch of settings in a window and offer different ways for the user to set them (TextBox, ListBox, etc).

One column has the names of the settings, and the other has the controls.  Should I use a ListView for that?  Can I use data binding?  How do I specify a different control per row in the ListView?

Comment: Basically I want to replicate the ListView from "Properties" window in the XAML editor of Visual Studio.  Names in one column, checkboxes/textboxes/listboxes in the other column.

Answer (score 0):

if each setting is of a different type you can data template them accordingly.

if they are all the same type you can use a DataTemplateSelector to choose an appropriate selector

[example](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) and [another one](http://mikestedman.blogspot.com/2009/04/datatemplateselector.html)

if you want multiple columns in a list view use a GridView, [see here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1)